# .htaccess file not working after adding custom url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to just update my .htaccess file so that I get nicer looking url's (without the file extenstion of .php). The file already has a redirect in it as I have both domain names.

Here is the original code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^darrenmorton\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.darrenmorton\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/darrenmorton\.co\.uk\/" [R=301,L]
```

And here is my updated code that is not working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^darrenmorton\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.darrenmorton\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/darrenmorton\.co\.uk\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Not 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^contact-darren-morton.php$ contact-darren-morton.php [L]
```

Not sure what is the problem as I am new to .htaccess files!

Comment: Can you give an example of a request you're making and the expected result?

Comment: @Erik Mitchell I am trying to get rid of the file extension at the end of the url string. So instead of www.website.com/page.php I would be getting www.website.com/page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?darrenmorton\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://darrenmorton.co.uk}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this. I tried it on my site but received the same error message. I have no idea why as I'm sure your code is perfect. I am now thinking that it must be a problem perhaps with the server set up? I will look into that and hopefully be able to use your code once I asked my host about the set up.

Comment: I have made a minor update in my code. Try it now and if it doesn't work let me know more details like location of this .htaccess, what URL did you try and what error did you get,

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting everything with that statement:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/darrenmorton\.co\.uk\/" [R=301,L]
```

Nothing after that will ever work, because it is the last rule to be checked if it matches (and it matches always). Defined by you with the `[L]`.

So at least you need to change the order of your rules. If you want the rules to only work on your .co.uk domain you have other options, too.

Comment: I just want it to work on the .co.uk because the .com is just for redirect to the .co.uk as there is no site on the .com If I move the original files (example in the starting post) to the bottom of the .htaccess file should it work? I am totally new to .htaccess files. I will give this a go anyway but just dont want to break anything.

Comment: If the files for the other domain are in another folder, you can add a .htaccess with your rules there.

Comment: actually you have just got me thinking now. I should be able to just do the redirect from the .com domain name back to .co.uk. I can then remove the redirect from the .htaccess file and just put the url string code in. If this works I will post back in order to help other who may have the same problem...

Comment: That is what I would do ;-)